# What's the schema or design pattern for arbitrary data?

Tags: json, parse-platform, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

Let's say I have millions of different kinds of JSON objects or documents, each unique with some of their own attributes.

Each column will be different and there could be millions of each kind of JSON objects, but I don't really know ahead of time what they will look like.

How do you model the schema or design pattern to store them?

Examples of similar services are things like Parse.com that seem to do what I aim to do but I don't know how they work and try as I might, I can't find technical info about how they work.

Comment: Maybe you don't model the schema at all, if they don't really have one. Use a schema-free persistence store, like MongoDB or some other NoSQL database.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That's what I was thinking, and in the case of all of them it works out. But with Parse you can run queries against the attributes. I could easily just tell whatever store I use to say "Here is some metadata, oh, and the Item I want to store, too". I was hoping to avoid mongodb because of the costs involved. 

Decided to go with MongoDB, in the end.